# How to access logs of another program ran on subprocess in Python

Tags: python, logging

I am having a difficulty in applying the logging module of Python to do what I want. Well, I am currently running `prog2.py` in `prog1.py` via subprocess module

```
input_args = ['python', '/path/to/prog2.py'] + self.chosen_args
self.process = Popen((input_args), stdout=PIPE)
```

What I want to do is, access the log that `prog2.py` prints but I don't know how. Am I gonna access `prog2.py`'s main class via `logging.getLogger('prog2Classname')`? I do not own `prog2.py`'s code but I want to save the log that it prints in a log file after. Can someone help me? Any tips will do.

Answer (score 0):

If prog2.py prints to stdout, you can redirect output to your own log file.

```
input_args = ['python',   '/path/to/prog2.py'] + self.chosen_args
file = open("your own log file.txt",'w')
self.process = Popen((input_args), stdout=file)
```

Comment: I did this but the logs of `prog2.py` still shows in the terminal. Do I need to use StreamHandler of the logging module for this? Because prog2.py is an open source software and it's not mine.

Comment: Whoo, solved it. `stderr` was where the logs redirect. Just redirected them to the text logfile now. Thanks @Azeezah

Comment: Glad I could help :)